# Laravel try to load files from old folder

Tags: iis, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-5.6, php-7.2

For some reasons, I had to change my project to another folder. I moved as a new project, I mean, using composer to install "vendor" folder as a new project.

My problem is, laravel (v5.6) is trying to load the files from old folder and I can't understand why is doing that. I have 6 years using this framework and this is the first time I saw that problem.

I cleaned cache from, browser, laravel project, the server (IIS), and composer.

When I want to generate a new key using artisan. But it is creating the key for .env in the old folder, not the current one.

I can't understand what the heck is going on?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem searching file by file...

Laravel is creating a file named "config.php" into folder "bootstrap/cache". That file must be deleted when you install the project on a new folder.

I lost lot of time for that!